# JMX Integration with Apache CXF

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, cxf, jmx

I need CXF server monitoring with JMX and followed [CXF Documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jmx-management.html). I use tomcat and following is the content of my `cxf.xml` file located at `/home/kalpa/applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/java_first_jaxws/WEB-INF/classes`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

<bean id="org.apache.cxf.management.InstrumentationManager" class="org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl">
  <property name="bus" ref="cxf" />
  <property name="enabled" value="true" />
  <property name="JMXServiceURL " value="service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9914/jmxrmi" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

But I cannot monitor the data with `jconsole`. There is no local entry for the connection.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your question is still an ongoing problem but this is my configuration :

```
  <cxf:bus bus="cxf">
    <cxf:properties>
      <entry key="bus.jmx.enabled" value="true"/>
      <entry key="bus.jmx.JMXServiceURL" value="service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9914/jmxrmi"/>
    </cxf:properties>
  </cxf:bus>
```

Instead of yours :

```
<bean id="org.apache.cxf.management.InstrumentationManager" class="org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl">
  <property name="bus" ref="cxf" />
  <property name="enabled" value="true" />
  <property name="JMXServiceURL " value="service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9914/jmxrmi" />
</bean>
```

I'm working with CXF 3.0.2, and a jconsole in JRE 1.6.0_27 ...

This is working fine :

[jconsole connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UULGO.png)